# Sourcetree "git clone" gives error "fatal: ArgumentOutOfRangeException encountered. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Tags: windows, git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

When git cloning a repo in the Command Prompt of Windows 10,

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/nyxynyx/test
```

a screen from Sourcetree *v2.6.10.0* appears asking for the login credentials

[image]

**Problem:** After I enter the username and password and click *Continue* button, the Command Prompt shows the error

> fatal: ArgumentOutOfRangeException encountered.
>
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Parameter name: resultType
>
> Username for 'https://bitbucket.org':

Now if I enter the same username and password, the `git clone` completes successfully.

Why is this error happening? How can we avoid Sourcetree popping up this dialog box and enter the login credentials directly in the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The pop up credential login window is not asked by SourceTree but by **Credential Manager**.

You can also refer the issue [Bitbucket - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/651).

And the issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/pull/656) now.